# Does revert commit in parent branch affect child branch

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. I have my "dev" branch. In which I have mistakenly committed "nextPhaseCommit1". Then I have created "nextPhaseDev" branch.
Now I have to revert the commit "nextPhaseCommit1" from "dev" branch.
Does this affect "nextPhaseCommit1" related code from "nextPhaseDev" branch?
In future I want to merge back "nextPhaseDev" to "dev". 
Does the revert operation will affect the merge?

Comment: There is no parent-child relation in git for branches.

Comment: Did you use `git revert` to revert the commit?

Comment: [The git documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc) is your friend. You may also have a look at [this one](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

`git revert` does not actually remove any commits. It creates a new commit with the inverted content of the "reverted" commit.

There is nothing you can do to a "parent" branch that affects a "child" branch. In this context you can view a branch as a pointer to a commit. A pointer to a commit is not affected if you create more commits which are pointed to by some other pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this affect "nextPhaseCommit1" related code from "nextPhaseDev" branch?

No, the revert happened on *dev* so *nextPhaseDev* is not affected.

> In future I want to merge back "nextPhaseDev" to "dev". Does the revert operation will affect the merge?

If commits on *nextPhaseDev* touched the same code that was reverted then you might have a merge conflict. If not then the code on *dev* will be as it was before the mistaken commit.

Hope that helps!